# Compiling opencv samples: unknown cmake command ocv_check_dependencies

Tags: opencv, cmake, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to build the OpenCV samples which come with the source package and I get the following:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (ocv_check_dependencies):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_check_dependencies".
```

I did install OpenCV using

```
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

and I got a tutorial snippet working (thus I suppose it is installed correctly as a library). However, compiling the samples does not work.

I guess I have to somehow configure CMake to have “ocv_check_dependencies” - but how? I am lost!

Comment: have you tried an out-of-source build?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got it.

In order to build the samples one has to change the default configuration for cmake by providing it via `-D`. What I did wrong was that I tried to execute cmake from within the `samples` directory.

The proper way to build the samples is invoking cmake like so (from within the root directory of the unpacked archive):

```
cmake -DBUILD_SAMPLES .
```

which will turn samples ON. One can proceed using make, make install than. The samples can be found in `bin` after building.

See also [FAQ](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV%20GPU%20FAQ#Are_there_any_samples.3F)

Comment: Thanks for this! I spot a couple of typos, though. A missed space and examples rather than samples. Do you mean `cmake -D BUILD_EXAMPLES .`?

Comment: On my machine it did not work with a space. They speak of samples and it really is "BUILD_SAMPLES". According to the documentation it is `-D BUILD_SAMPLES=ON`, however the above worked for me.

Comment: I tried `BUILD_SAMPLES` and it wouldn't work, so I looked in the CMakeLists file and saw `BUILD_EXAMPLES`. I was using the Unix source, maybe you're using another one? Anyway, these comments will be here for anybody else who has this problem

Comment: It seems like you 're running cmake in a source directory. Not recommended AFAIK

Answer (score 22):

Actually for OpenCV 2.4.4 beta the root CMakeList.txt file says:

> OCV_OPTION(BUILD_EXAMPLES  "Build all examples"

`-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON` worked just fine for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON` is used across all documentation. See for example [the linux tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html).

Answer (score 3):

How to compile OpenCV sample code ?

```
# For OpenCV 3 
cd /path/to/opencv/samples/cpp/
#Compile
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` facedetect.cpp -o facedetect
#run
./facedetect
```

Works for me.

[googled from this link](http://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-compile-opencv-sample-code/)

Comment: @drewish Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

mydragonisland's build instructions almost worked for me; with a minor reordering and including accents:

```
g++ facedetect.cpp -o facedetect `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Answer (score 1):

The macro 'ocv_check_dependencies' is defined in: your_path_to/opencv/cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake

```
# ensures that all passed modules are available
# sets OCV_DEPENDENCIES_FOUND variable to TRUE/FALSE
macro(ocv_check_dependencies)
  set(OCV_DEPENDENCIES_FOUND TRUE)
  foreach(d ${ARGN})
    if(d MATCHES "^opencv_[^ ]+$" AND NOT HAVE_${d})
      set(OCV_DEPENDENCIES_FOUND FALSE)
      break()
    endif()
  endforeach()
endmacro()
```

The top level CMakeLists.txt contains 'include' commands for files from  opencv/cmake/ . Which is why the macro is available when you compile by calling cmake from the root of the opencv sources.

Comment: If my answer helped you please give it an up vote, so that other users know. 
Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Sure, it's my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

### Reason

error message context:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (ocv_check_dependencies):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_check_dependencies".
```

This error message happens because cmake can't find the definition of `ocv_check_dependencies`

That's why the console said **Unknown CMake command**

### Solution

If cmake cannot find where `ocv_check_dependencies` is defined

Just like @Nick Hockings Said:

`ocv_check_dependencies` is a macro defined in `Your/OpenCV/path/OpenCVModule.cmake`

```
macro(ocv_check_dependencies)
  set(OCV_DEPENDENCIES_FOUND TRUE)
  foreach(d ${ARGN})
    if(d MATCHES "^opencv_[^ ]+$" AND NOT HAVE_${d})
      set(OCV_DEPENDENCIES_FOUND FALSE)
      break()
    endif()
  endforeach()
endmacro()
```

The fastest way is to copy this snippet above to your `CMakeList.txt` file right above where `ocv_check_dependencies` is

Therefore, cmake can finally understand what it is

That should do the trick, i hope no one else will bother with this question in the future

Answer (score 0):

I got similar errors. My approach is as following:
1) cd xxx/samples 2) mkdir build 3) cd build 4) cmake .. 5) make
Now it works. We could not build individual project under their source files.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps works for me.

Export toolchain path.

cd opencv-3.3.0/samples

cross_cmake && 
cross_make

cd opencv-3.3.0/samples/cpp/