# How to run multi cpp in a project in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm a newbie in C++ programing, I wan to practice each exercise on each seperate cpp files in the same project. How can I do this because VS will result error but I still want to manage all exercises in a project and don't want to make multi-projects for each of them.

Comment: You can't. Have a separate project for each `main()`entry level program. These can all exist in a single solution file though.

Comment: You can right-click on a source file in the Solution Explorer and select "Properties".  Under the props dialog that appears, the first option is "Excluded from Build".  You can toggle the Exclude property on/off if you are doing what you describe.

Comment: It will look something like this when you add multiple projects [PHOTO](https://imgur.com/dUrER7f)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple main CPP files in VisualStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022538/multiple-main-cpp-files-in-visualstudio)

Comment: thanks, the second paragraph really help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the files that you don't want to use in the Cmake file.
For example you have files: ex1.h, ex1.cpp ex2.h, ex2.cpp, ex3.cpp
In your Cmake file you have `set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp ex1.h ex1.cpp ex2.h ex2.cpp ex3.cpp)`
If you want to execute only ex1 delete ex2 and ex3 files.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recurring issue when you are a student and would like that each exercise works as a standalone application without the overhead of having 100+ projects within the same solution.

The trick is to exclude the file(s) by excluding it from build in its properties, as illustrated in the screenshot below.

[image: Excluding a file from build]

Used this method for several years without any issue at the university. :)

Comment: Excellent! Don't hesitate to mark the answer as the solution using the little tick. :)