# Can I use multiple main function under a project on Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide

I am using Visual studio 2019 for learning C++. Every time I am crating project for each program. Is it possible to crate and run multiple main source file on Visual Studio like Java on Eclipse/Netbeans/IntellijIdea? Thank you.

Comment: Short answer **you can and you cant't** have multiple main function in an application, in Java *i think* you can do so. But in c++ **main()** is the entry point of your application. This means if main() is not present the code will not compile. If it's present the code will start execution from it.

Comment: Are you aware of solutions and projects? If not: you can create several projects in a solution and start them independently.
I'm not sure if this suites your question, but maybe it's worth mentioning

Comment: The problem is each project represents at most 1 executable and you can't have two main() functions in the same executable. You can however have multiple projects in a workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer "You can't and you can".

main() is called an entry point. In Java you can have `main()` in every class because each class can be **self-contained** in theory.

C++ doesn't work like this because at the end every thing get linked to a single executable.

If you want to have multiple entry points You need to:

1. Create seperate ***.cpp** file for every entry point, each file should define its own main() function.
2. Each file should have a separate binary target in your build system(Cmake...etc)
3. Build & Run target as needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways of doing it. Either you use `cmake`, more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146650/compiling-opencv-samples-unknown-cmake-command-ocv-check-dependencies)

or

you put the main functions in separate namespaces and then define, which one do you want to run. [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17022559/13696354)

Comment: Answer must be self-contained.