# Error while building opencv_contrib opencv 3.0

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, cmake, opencv3.0

I wanted to use the "extra" modules, that come as opencv_contrib from [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) for other functions of opencv 3.0. I followed the instructions as per the page, for building and compiling the modules, but am stuck with this error

```
    Command:
    cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules ..

    Error:
    <Skipping the common Cmake statements and going straight to the error>
    CMake Error at opencv_contrib/modules/adas/tools/fcw_train/CMakeLists.txt:16 (ocv_include_modules_recurse):

    Unknown CMake command "ocv_include_modules_recurse".

    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I checked the **CMakeLists.txt** as mentioned in the path and there were other lines of code that had **ocv_xxx** , thus it was not a rename issue (I thought they misspelt opencv).

This is my folder structure:

```
    Opencv
          - build
          - opencv_contrib
```

This is to verify if my CMake command was correct, as I had posted above.

Can you please tell me how to rectify this error?

**UPDATE 1**

As per a suggestion, I tried,by putting the `opencv_contrib` folder outside the opencv folder structure. The new structure was like this

```
    -Opencv
           - build
    -opencv_contrib
```

and my new command was

```
    cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

the error is still the same.

Comment: just a *gut feeling* , but maybe do not put your opencv_contrib things *inside* the opencv main structure. put it elsewhere, and reference it like : cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/some/other/folder/where/you/put/the/contrib/parts

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @berak. please look at the update

Comment: sorry no idea, count me out. no idea, what the error means..

Comment: @berak not related to the question, but I am facing issue with findnonzero and in one of the bug report page, found your name pop up. Any help on how to solve it? it throws error if no nonzero pixels were found.

Comment: oh, that one. to my knowledge, [it's corrected now](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3828#note-3) . ( just pull again)

Comment: I saw that @berak. how do I reflect it in my code? should I download and install new? or manually change the code? am not able to get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77456/discussion-between-lakshmi-narayanan-and-berak).

Comment: try a fresh git pull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146650/compiling-opencv-samples-unknown-cmake-command-ocv-check-dependencies) question. From that question, I understood that the value of the argument should be correct, to turn on the build or something like that. So I changed my command from

```
    cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib/modules ..
```

to

```
    cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=opencv_contrib/modules .
```

Plain and simple, without hierarchy information and it worked. Cheers.